# C++ subscripting operator [] for a Vector class using unique pointers

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm writing my own vector class using `malloc`. In particular, to provide **a minimial example** I just show the constructor and the subscripting operator `[]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T>
class Vector{
  std::unique_ptr<T,decltype(&free)> elem{nullptr,free}; 
  std::size_t _size{};
  std::size_t _capacity{};

public:
      
  Vector() = default;
  ~Vector(){
    for(auto i = 0; i <_size; ++i){
      // invoke the destructor
    }

  }

  Vector(std::initializer_list<T> list): // pass by value
    elem{static_cast<T*>(malloc(list.size()*sizeof(T))), free},
    _size{list.size()},
    _capacity{list.size()}{

    std::uninitialized_copy(list.begin(), list.end(), elem.get());
  }


  auto& operator[](const std::size_t i){
    return elem[i];
  }

 const auto& operator[](const std::size_t i) const{
    return elem[i];
  }
  
  
  
};
```

Then I implemented the classical `push_back()`, but all the errors I got come from the following:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const std::unique_ptr<int, void (*)(void*)>’ and ‘const size_t’ {aka ‘const long unsigned int’})
   80 |     return elem[i];
```

**It seems that the problem is that I can't access the `i`-th element of my `unique_ptr`, but I really can't understant what's the problem!** How can I fix this, so that all the other functions I implemented work? Also, what is the problem in my `elem[i]` is `elem` is a `unique_prt`?

Comment: The shown code apparently is operating under a mistaken notion that `unique_ptr` is some kind of an array-like object that has an overloaded `[]` operator? It is not anything like that. `elem` is a `std::unique_ptr`. In order for `elem[i]` to work `std::unique_ptr` needs to overload the `[]` operator. It does not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I got your point. But how can I enable that my `std::unique_prt` has the `[]` operator?

Comment: You mean the pointer stored in your `std::unique_ptr`? Use its `get()` method to retrieve the stored pointer, and use the `[]` operator on it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so like `elem.get()[i]`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at)

Comment: It works! :-) Thanks so much @SamVarshavchik Btw, I am a bit confused now: `unique_ptr` express the idea of unique ownership. Also I've seen plenty of codes declaring unique pointers like `std::unique_ptr<T[]> elem;` and then using `[]` operator without the need to use the function `get()`.Why do you say that is does not overload the operator `[]`?

Comment: @bloody Okay, so the operator `[]` is already overloaded... but why does it work in my case only if I use `elem.get()[i]` instead of `elem[i]`?

Comment: @bloody So the issue was that `malloc` just allocated memory, while using `new` I also provide the `[]` operator when my type is `std::unique_ptr`, because it's an array type, right?

Comment: Oh, and you must add brackets also in the declaration: `std::unique_ptr<T[], ...`

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr<T>` doesn't have `operator[]`, but `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` does.

So you might use

```
std::unique_ptr<T[], decltype(&free)> elem{nullptr,free};
```

Note: using class for deleter allows Empty Base Optimization (EBO), and simplify call site:

```
struct Free
{
    void operator()(void* p) const { free(p); }
};


std::unique_ptr<T[], Free> elem{nullptr};
```